# clang-analyzer-alpha.unix.PthreadLock check missing from clang-tidy version 3.8 and 4.0?

Tags: c++11, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-4.0

I am trying to modernize my module's C++ source code using clang-tidy. A few weeks ago, I downloaded and built [clang and clang tools](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) version 3.9 and when I ran it on one of my cpp files I got `clang-analyzer-alpha.unix.PthreadLock` saying that lock has already been taken.

Later, because of space constraints I removed that version of clang and used version 3.8 and 4.0 available in our 3rd party repos.

In both of these versions, I did not get any warnings regarding this alpha check. How do I enable it in version 4.0 ?

I am already using `-checks=*` while analyzing/running clang-tidy on my cpp file.

Comment: Clang 4.0? Do you mean the trunk version?

Comment: @JVApen Yes. I meant the trunk version.

Comment: It is available in [the overview](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/alpha_checks.html), so I would expect that `-checks=*` should check it, unless `-checks=*,alpha.*` would be required

Comment: Using `-checks=*,alpha.*` did not help. Neither did `-checks=alpha.*`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no way to enable those checks without building clang-tidy yourself: https://reviews.llvm.org/D28729#646548.