# clang-tidy 4.0 clang-analyzer-alpha.unix.PthreadLock check

Tags: c++11, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-4.0

Even after I thought that this [check was missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200539/clang-analyzer-alpha-unix-pthreadlock-check-missing-from-clang-tidy-version-3-8), I am now suddenly getting the output of `clang-analyzer-alpha.unix.PthreadLock` check from the clang-tidy 4.0 tool. Here is a toned down use case of my code which I am trying to modernize by using clang-tidy tool. 
I have enabled all the checks using `-checks=*` argument.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/once.hpp>

void foo2()
{
    boost:mutex mymutex;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mymutex);       
    int* x = NULL; // This is intentional. This triggers the clang-tidy checks. If I remove this lines, I wont get the clang-tidy warnings/errors/recommendations.
}
int main() {

    foo2();
    return 0;
}
```

When clang-tidy is ran over this code,it produces following warnings.

```
path/boost/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:149:23: warning: This lock has already been acquired [clang-analyzer-alpha.unix.PthreadLock]
            int res = posix::pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
                      ^
path/Source.cpp:40:5: note: Calling 'foo2'
    foo2();
    ^
path/Source.cpp:32:31: note: Calling constructor for 'unique_lock'
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(getMutex());    
                              ^
path/boost/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:157:7: note: Calling 'unique_lock::lock'
      lock();
      ^
path/boost/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:369:7: note: Taking false branch
      if (m == 0)
      ^
path/boost/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:374:7: note: Taking false branch
      if (owns_lock())
      ^
path/boost/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:379:7: note: Calling 'mutex::lock'
      m->lock();
      ^
path/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:149:23: note: This lock has already been acquired
            int res = posix::pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
                      ^
path/Source.cpp:34:10: warning: unused variable 'x' [clang-diagnostic-unused-variable]
    int* x = NULL; 
         ^
path/Source.cpp:34:14: warning: use nullptr [modernize-use-nullptr]
    int* x = NULL; 
             ^
             nullptr
Suppressed 33125 warnings (33125 in non-user code).
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
```

Why does clang-tidy think that this lock has already been taken? Two functions are totally apart and the lock inside `foo2` has no relation to lock in the boost headers. Is this an incorrect warning ? If not then what should I do about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 4.0 has not been released at this time, so I assume you built it yourself from whatever SVN revision was the latest when you checked out the code. I think you should file a bug report at LLVM instead of asking here.

Comment: [Bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30408) filed.